# Firebase authenication only for one user

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I made a website and setup up a firebase signup for it. But I don't want users to signup with their emails. As the Website should be only accessed by a specific email and password which I would provide. How can I setup this functionality. Can someone explain the process.

Comment: Well why are you setting up a signup if users shouldn't be allowed to sign up? Just create the account beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the email/password account manually in the Firebase console
2. Give the account information to the user
3. Code the account password to the user, and code a way for them to sign in with the Firebase Auth SDK.